# Why are people so eager to answer questions and get reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, gamification

What benefits does gaining reputation give you outside of giving you access to basic functions?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18888/why-do-you-post-to-stack-overflow

Comment: if you ask a question and get on answer from someone with say 23 rep, just as an example; and a different answer from someone with say, 699k rep, which one do you think is likey to to be more reliable?  The purpose is more related to qualifying answers.

Comment: Agree with @Plutonix. Enhanced editing capabilities, voting up and down, et cetera, are *perks* for users who have proven to be reliable. They are not meant as "targets" of any kind.

Comment: Chicks dig rep.

Comment: @splungebob I dunno... I'd rather have the rep myself than admire some guy with tons of it. :)

Comment: Some people just like to help others out. Go figure. :)

Comment: Disagree with @Plutonix.  However, it largely is a self-correcting problem.  The person who at 23 rep, provides very good answers, probably isn't going to be at 23 rep for very long.

Comment: Johnny, I'd split out this question into two parts. It's better asked as "Why are people so eager to answer questions?". Reputation is the gaming system that undoubtedly contributes to the site's success, but it's not the only reason why people help. As you grow in rep you'll find that your attitude to it changes up and down - I don't care so much for it now, but I do enjoy helping people. Don't know why, really. Just be aware it can be addictive, and from time to time it's good to shut the computer off and get some sunshine `8-D`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)... even though the company that hired me for my most recent role didn't actively use Careers 2.0, they used the answers and reputation I've acquired on Stack Overflow as a criteria in giving me this job.  If you manage to get a job interview with someone that actively knows what reputation on Stack Overflow is, you're ahead of the game.

Comment: I completely forgot about careers. I haven't ever used it, so it's easy enough to forget about for me.

Comment: "We have shut down Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story as of April 1, 2022"

Answer (score 6):

Reputation unlocks different privileges. Up to 20k, you unlock new tools and abilities at certain milestones. For instance, you were able to come to Meta because you gained at least 5 rep.

At higher reps, you gain access to various tools.

1. At 500 points, you gain access to a couple of the review queues,
   namely first post and late answer.
2. At 2000, you can edit posts
   without that going to the review queue.
3. At 3000, you gain access to close and reopen votes
4. At 10000, you can access other review queues and see deleted posts

Note this isn't a complete list. You can view the complete list on the [privileges page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Other than that, some people just like to gain imaginary internet points.

Comment: What kind of tools do you get at that high of a reputation? I imagine it would take a very long time to get that high

Comment: @johnny93 I've added a list of highlights. There are others- But these are some of the bigger ones.

Comment: If you write good answers and ask well-researched and well-written questions, you'll hit 500 in no time. You can also edit posts to gain some rep.

Comment: @johnny93: It doesn't have to take very long if you're somewhat active. I joined a little less than 4 months ago, and should reach 10k in another 1-2 months if I continue at the same pace.

Comment: as far as I know, "new abilities" are unlocked [up to 180K](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136023/165773 "as explained here")

Comment: @gnat I never knew that. That is... Going to take a long time for me. Oh well- I never needed fancy things anyway. :) But thank you for the lesson!

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yeh, it doesn't have to take long if you are a true master of an API, using it every day since it was released 22+ years ago. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I, for one, appreciate having a socially acceptable outlet for my tendency toward insufferable pedantry.